# Calculate the factorial of a number

Tags: python

1. Define a function called `calculate_factorial` that takes in one parameter, `number`.
2. Inside the function, write code to calculate the factorial of the given number.
3. The factorial of a number is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to that number. For example, the factorial of 5 is 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120.
4. You can use either loops or recursion to calculate the factorial.
5. Return the factorial as the output of the function.

Hello everybody! I've just started to learn Python and I have difficulties already. I am stuck on this task. I've tried to use both - loops and recursion but at the end it still an error ( EOF Error). And how exactly should I return the factorial (task 5). Could you help me to solve this? Thank you!

I tried this:
def calculate_factorial(number):
print(4)
calculate_factorial(4)

def factorial(n):
if n < 0:
return 0
elif n == 0 or n == 1:
return 1
else:
fact = 1
while(n > 1):
fact *= n
n -= 1
return fact
num = 4
print("Factorial of",num,"is",factorial(num))

Your code failed this test
Error details
None != 1

Comment: Can you share your code as well?

Comment: Code _and_ full exception message (even if it is long).

Comment: Post you're code, along with information about how it fails, and a specific question about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible method using a `while` loop:

```
factorial_base = int(input('Enter a positive integer:\n'))  # The number to factorialize.
factorial = 1

if factorial_base > 0:  # 0! = 1, so if the base is 0, just leave the factorial value as default (1).
    while factorial_base != 1:
        factorial *= factorial_base
        factorial_base -= 1
```

Essentially, this will multiply 1 by the given number to factorialize (i.e. n), then by (n - 1), then by (n - 2), and so on, until the multiplication factor reaches 1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative approach:

```
def calculate_factorial(n):
    factorial = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        factorial *= i
    return factorial
```

Recursive:

```
def calculate_factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * calculate_factorial(n-1)
```

It would be great if you could share the code that you tried.

Comment: Don't just post outright solutions when OP hasn't even shown you their code.  How does this help OP understand the problem with *their* code?  It doesn't.

Comment: Please see [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) concerning homework questions.

Comment: Thank you very much,  Dash! I have done it! I forgot to type "print" that why I failed!

Answer (score 0):

To help with solving your problem and learning the concept of functions, please see [this website](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function) that explains:

1. How to define functions (like `calculate_factorial`).
2. How to pass arguments (like `number`).
3. How to return something from a function.

In addition, here is a tutorial on for loops and using the `range()` function from [this source](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

The above should help you write your function. See [this website](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/factorial.html) if you need more information on how to calculate a number factorial.

Answer (score 0):

Factorial is defined that 1! = 1 and n! = n * (n - 1)! = the product of all integers from 1 to n, so just multiply the numbers one by one.

Here is a concise implementation:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import imul

def factorial(n):
    return reduce(imul, range(1, n + 1), 1)
```

But in actual code, use `math.factorial`:

```
In [517]: def factorial(n): return reduce(imul, range(1, n + 1), 1)

In [518]: factorial(25)
Out[518]: 15511210043330985984000000

In [519]: %timeit factorial(25)
2.29 µs ± 422 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [520]: import math

In [521]: %timeit math.factorial(25)
417 ns ± 22.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But we have not learnt "math.factorial" and another tools. So I can not use this

Comment: @Johnny Nah, I don't think those useless programming courses will ever teach you these advanced techniques. Your teacher probably doesn't know this, too. I never went to any programming course and learned programming all by myself. You accepted inefficient methods.

Comment: Ξένη Γήινος, as I said before, I have just started. I think we will learn it but later.

Answer (score -1):

def calculate_factorial(number):
for i in range(1, number):
number *= i
return number
ans=calculate_factorial(7)
print(ans)

Comment: `range(1, number)` doesn't include `number`. So for example `calculate_factorial(5)` will return 24, not 120.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).